# How to determine if a DraggableScrollableController is animating in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, listener

I have a `DraggableScrollableSheet` that has a `DraggableScrollableController`. I'm calling `.animateTo()` on the `DraggableScrollableController`. Is there any way to tell outside of the sheet, in another widget maybe, that the sheet is animating? Some kind of `isAnimating` type property where the default is `false`, then when you call `animateTo` and you check this property it is `true` and when it completes, back to `false`?

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap it with `NotificationListener`:

this will show the `extent` of your `draggableScrollableSheet`.

```
NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {

    print("${notification.extent}");
  },
  child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: .70,
      minChildSize: .70,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollcontroller) {
        return Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              controller: scrollcontroller,
              itemCount: widget.songs.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return buildSongRow(widget.songs[index]);
              }),
        );
      }),
)
```

then you can set some logic like this :

```
bool isAnimating = notification.extent != notification.maxExtent;
```

please try it and tell me.

Comment: That condition always returns true for me.